# IF Function 2 outcomes

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

I have a meeting reading sheet with opening and closing readings where I have a simple formula subtracting the closing from the opening to give a consumption reading. I need to add a purchases column for when we top up the meter but now the simple subtraction formula gives an incorrect consumption result as it does not take the purchase column into account. I have tried using IF function to say IF the cell in column C is greater than zero to add the purchases to the closing consumption but it returns "false".

I think I need a combined IF function for the one cell. IF there are any unit purchases I need it to take them into account when subtracting from the previous days reading by adding them first. Does that make sense?)

=IF(C10>0,D9+C10-D10,"")

Comment: If the purchases column is either a number or blank, you can just add it in regardless, with no need for an IF function at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you're looking for, but I can tell you that nested `IF`-constructions are ok in Excel, but it might need some preparation, e.g.:

Start with a logical way of writing your `IF`-clause:

```
IF cond1 AND cond2
THEN Result = R1
ELSE IF cond3
     THEN Result = R2
     ELSE Result = R3
```

This can be written in an Excel-formula as:

```
=IF(AND(cond1;cond2);R1;IF(cond3;R2;R3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is Cross-posted at

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1417227-if-function-meter-reading-sheet.html